# Trim or hide Highchart legends based on number of legends

Tags: javascript, ember.js, highcharts

Is there an option or formatter to hide or trim Highcharts v6 legends based on number of legends or text count?

eg: if there are 100 legends then display only 20 and a more button which can show all or show all in tooltip. Like in below image show only 6 legends and hide others.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict the area that the legend is displayed in and have navigation to scroll through the entire list.
http://jsfiddle.net/t3uah5k0/1/

```
legend: {
    maxHeight: 40
},
```

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend

There isn't a built in function to show all or show all in a tooltip. But you could change the maxHeight based on some event.